# Does Ubuntu store sudo password in cache?

Tags: sudo, password

If we fire a command with `sudo` in terminal, it asks for password for the first time and if we fire another command with `sudo` immediately in same terminal, it won't ask for password again. Why is it so ?

Does Ubuntu store the `sudo` password for sometime in cache? Can anyone else (another program/malware) use that password during that time span ?

Comment: It is called "keyring"

Comment: "Keyring is a collection of components in GNOME that store secrets, passwords, keys, certificates and make them available to applications."   This is what is stated here --> http://askubuntu.com/questions/32164/what-does-a-keyring-do 

Are you sure keyring itself is used for `sudo` ?

Comment: @Zanna : Thank you for the edits.  I appreciate that. :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for marking it as duplicate and redirecting me to correct answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is it so? Comfort I guess. You wouldn't use sudo if you had to type your password every 2 seconds.

`sudo` does not remember your password. `sudo` remembers the date, user and terminal. If a `sudo` command in the same terminal is executed by the same user in a short period of time (15 minutes by default), `sudo` just doesn't ask for the password again.

`sudo` needs your password to make sure you are really you, and not someone else while you're away drinking coffee. it does not need your password to switch to root, since it runs as root.

If, from the same terminal, you run some malware within the grace period, the malware may be able to `sudo` without a password.

You may use `sudo -k` to invalidate the cache.

Comment: your last line talks about invalidating the cache, which means invalidating the timestamp details, isn't it ? 

Has it been documented officially anywhere that `sudo` does not store password but timestamp details only ?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no documentation that sudo does not need your password, and thus does not store it. This is just pure logic. I must admit I should've used the source. But again, sudo does not need a password, because it is root and can switch to any uid/gid whenever it wants to. Moreover, it is possible to create configuration where sudo won't even ask your password. see the `NOPASSWD:` in the sudoers man page. If sudo can switch user without storing a password, why would it store it ? And why would it store your password if it is not going to ask you the password again ?

Comment: I read the answer on duplicate question and your explanation exactly matches it. 
Marked yours as answer here. 
Thanks.