# What is keyring default

Tags: 12.04

Everytime I log on line this pops up " Enter password for keyring 'Default' to unlock " what does it mean? I do not know where to look for this password, I do not know the password that it wants.

Comment: What program do you use to "log on line"? What changes have you made to your system? Have you tried your login password?

Answer (score 5):

I guess your configuration looks like this:

- Your browser is Chromium, Chrome or similar
- You want to log in on a website to which your browser has stored the password
- You have automatic login for your Ubuntu user account enabled so that you need no password to log in.

The automatic login functionality allows you to unlock your account and start the user session, but it does not unlock your default keyring.

See [What does a Keyring do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32164/what-does-a-keyring-do) to learn more about those keyrings. Basically it is like a password-protected encrypted storage for all kinds of credentials, used by the system and also used by Chrome-like browsers to store web passwords.

And there is your problem, as you did not enter your password to log in to your Ubuntu user account, the default keyring is still encrypted and your browser can not read its stored logins for the site you want to visit from it. Therefore it shows a dialogue asking you for the correct password to unlock they keyring - your login password.